# Shopify API calls from a java external application

Tags: shopify

My clients have decided to open a store on Shopify, and they want a list of the items for sale there to be displayed in our website; which is built in jsp (liferay). I'm completely new to Shopify, so I've been checking around, but I'm getting confused.

There appears to be a "Shopify4J" library which should make calls to the API real simple, which is basically what I need (retrieve a list of all items from the store). However, I see all these examples with urls, and I've read that Shopify API can only be used from Shopify apps.

My question is, can I actually call the API from my website to retrieve the item list? Or do I have to create a Shopify app that would connect to my site via something like webservice?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the api and pull in the products, but I think a better solution would be to install the widget app and just embed the widget into your site. Much simple and does exactly what you want as far as I can tell.

Shopify Widget App: http://apps.shopify.com/shopify-widgets

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an Shopify API call, You'll have to first create a token. This can be done by going to Apps > Manage private apps and then click **Generate API Credentials**. You'll be provided with API Key and password to use in your call.

[Here](https://help.shopify.com/manual/apps/private-apps) is the documentation of private apps.

And [here](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference) is Shopify's api documentation.